# Python Unix Timestamp to formatted Date

Tags: python, date

I want to get a Date from a UNIX Timestamp in Python with the following code:

```
datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
```

with the timestamp being 1605532620337.2188, but I am getting this error:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Comment: That timestamp appears to be a *milliseconds*. You'll need to divide by 1000…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from datetime import datetime
print(datetime.fromtimestamp(1605532620337.2188 // 1000))
```

Output:

```
2020-11-16 14:17:00
```